# using nUnitASP in webforms

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I am new in Unit Testing. I have been asked that nUnitASP can be used to test WebForms. and it is already integrated in VS2008. I am not able to find any way in VS2008 for unit Testing ASP Webforms specifically.
Though I know the native method VS provide for UnitTesting, I am quite aware of NUnit using as seperate GUI. I am seeking for any suggestions from here... 
So my first question is :

Do VS2008 is coming with NUnit now?
What I need to do for testing ASP webforms in VS2008 integrated method?
Can I do the same using NUnit?
What is the difference between NUnit and nUnitASP?

Any help/suggestions in this regard are highly appreciated.

-Sumeet

Comment: http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/
Don't pick up a product that's not being developed, especially for a new endeavour. It will only to continue to fall further behind. Would you start a new business and buy telegraph machines because you know they send Morse code? -. --- / -.-- --- ..- / .-- --- ..- .-.. -.. -. .----. - .-.-.-

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NUnitASP is no longer being developed (as of Jan 2008): see [here](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/), though looks like you could still download it. It's an extension to NUnit, and does not come with VS 2008.
NUnit can be found [here](http://www.nunit.org). NUnit provides the core framework, and NUnitASP is just an extension on to it.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit does not come with Visual Studio. The Visual Studio Team System Developer Edition comes with a Web Test capability that can be used for some unit testing of web-based applications. It does *not* work the same way as nNunitASP.